# Rate Limiter not working for index page?

Tags: nginx

I am using this location block with php

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  limit_req zone=limit burst=3 nodelay;
  fastcgi_pass php_farm;
  include nginx.fastcgi.conf;
}
```

If I go to localhost/testxxx.php and start F5 spamming, the limit_req will work properly. **BUT**, if I just go to localhost and start refreshing/f5, nothing happens and it doesn't activate the limit_req, any idea? It seems like it's not catching my main index.php file because it's not shown in the URL? (localhost) with no trailing slash? Any idea how to catch index.php inside the location block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I finally found a fix after reviewing this awesome article:
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

I added this below my location block:

```
location = / {
            limit_req zone=limit burst=3 nodelay;
        }
```

And it catches the 'localhost' url!